# getElementsByTagName with multiple instances in HTML

Tags: html, vba, excel

having a bit of an issue with reading some HTML via VBA and can't seem to find any threads on here that have been able to solve issue. Here is a small chunk of the VBA, it does everything I need except for the last (most important) step which is to tell me whether or not a specific value exists within the HTML.

```
Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

promo = IE.Document.getElementById("formContent").getElementsByTagName("label")(1)

If InStr(promo.innerText, Range("E5").Value) = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i) = "No"
Else
    ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i) = "Yes"
End If

Next i

IE.Quit
```

Here's the HTML, I'm trying to check if the value in range E5 matches the value in one of the  tags (which on will change depending on the value of E5)... I can't seem to get it to look through these tags and tell me if E5 matches... stumped.

```
    <div id="formHeader">Personal Information:</div>
    <div id="formContent">
    Salutation:<br>
    <label class="formResult">MR</label> <br>
    First Name:<br>
    <label class="formResult">John</label> <br/>
    Middle Name:<br>
    <label class="formResult">P</label> <br/>
    Last Name:<br>
    <label class="formResult">Smith</label> <br>
    Preferred Name:<br>
    <label class="formResult">Johnny</label> <br>
    Date of Birth: <br>
    <label class="formResult">Mar 31, 1985</label> <br/>
    Gender:<br>
    <label class="formResult">M</label> <br/>
    Language:<br>
    <label class="formResult">E</label> <br/>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <div id="formHeader">Mailing Address:</div>
    <div id="formContent">Address Type: <br/>
    <label class="formResult">HOME</label> <br/>
    Mail Consent: <br/>
    <label class="formResult">Y</label> <br/>
    Address 1: <br/>
    <label class="formResult">101 Smith St</label> <br/>
    Address 2: <br/>
    <label class="formResult"></label> <br/>
    City: <br/>
    <label class="formResult">Happytown</label> <br/>
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You are only checking the first label, you need to loop through them all, according to your description. But your code is incomplete and cannot be representative: you have `Next i`, where does it begin?

Comment: @Andy G the `Next i` refers to a loop that goes through various values typed into the spreadsheet, to be honest I really only want to check one label, so I don't really need it to loop through all of them. That's why I have the (1) but it still give me an error rather then just checking it.

Comment: Are you checking one value, against all the labels? This point remains unclear.

Comment: @AndyG I don't really need to check one value against all labels as I know which label in particular will have the value I want to check (it's the "Y", I want to check if it's "Y" or "N"). I attempted to replace my code with the code you provided in your Answer (both) and just got various errors. First error didn't like the "Dim promos" line, sort of fixed that then ran into errors with the "Next i" so I just went back to my original code and trying to focus on the "promo =" line. There's got to be a way to choose the specific label tag I want, right?? Thank you for the suggestions though!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the full HTML ? and highlight which elements you want to compare the innertext with your cell ? The idea is to see where they are in the HTML so that we get the "pattern" and then we can do a loop to go through each of them and check

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop to iterate all the label elements would be:

```
Dim promos As IHTMLElementCollection

Set promos = ie.Document.getElementById("formContent").getElementsByTagName("label")
For Each promo In promos
    If InStr(promo.innerText, Range("E5").Value) = 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i) = "No"
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i) = "Yes"
    End If
Next
```

However, you need to exit the loop if the value is found.

Logically, set the text to "No" and only change it to "Yes" if the value is found. Then Exit.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i) = "No"
Dim promos As IHTMLElementCollection

Set promos = ie.Document.getElementById("formContent").getElementsByTagName("label")
For Each promo In promos
    If InStr(promo.innerText, Range("E5").Value) <> 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i) = "Yes"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I've implemented the your suggestions adjusted for certain errors but now I keep getting an "object required" error on the `For Each promo in promos` line... not sure if this has to do with not declaring "promo" as a variable? I feel like this is so close to working, just missing something simple on my end... Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Andy G Promos is missing the `Set` keyword. It should be `Set promos = ie.Document...`.

Comment: @DickPlixen Always declare your variables before asking for help :).

Comment: @AndyG Well that's fixed the "object required" error but now it throws a "Compile error: Type mismatch" on the `promos =` line. Sorry, not sure how to troubleshoot that... really seems like it should work but I'm a bit out of my element here.

Comment: @DickPlixen That means you are trying to assign a value of `Type X` to a variable of `Type Y`. If your variable is declared as an Object, it should assign. I would recommend declaring promos as variant, assigning it, and then using `TypeName(Promos)` (or the Locals window) to get the correct `Type`.

Comment: @BrandonBarney Thank you for pointing out the missing `Set`, I must have my .NET hat on ;)

Comment: @AndyG No worries :). It certainly can be tricky to switch between the two. The first time I had to write .NET I was completely thrown by the lack of `Set`.

Comment: I notice that the HTML is malformed anyway, id's must be unique on the page: two elements cannot have the same id.

Comment: Thanks for all the help on this @AndyG and @BrandonBarney, unfortunately I've come to the realization that I need this check the value of E5 against a specific child node of the "formContent" div... there are multiple lines in the html that could return a match. Is there are way to set the "promos" variable to point to a specific instance of the "formContent" Id? For instance... this would make sense to me `ie.Document.getElementById("formContent")(1).getElem...` but this throws an "object required error.

Comment: `GetElementByID` returns the first instance of a tag with the given ID. If you want to return all elements of a given tag use `GetElementsByClass` or `GetElementsByName` (hint: the functions tell you whether they return an item, `Element` or Collection of Items `Elements`.). You can then use indices to get to the item you need. You can also resort to `GetElementsByTag` (all of these are off the top of my head, use Intellisense to find the correct functions).

Comment: @BrandonBarney I agree the HTML is malformed... I thought it strange that multiple elements had the same id.

Comment: @BrandonBarney I tried to adjust to `GetElementsByClass("formResult")(2)` but I get an "Object doesn't support this property or method error". I really appreciate the help, I'm learning quite a few things I had no idea about!

Comment: @DickPlixen Did you use intellisense? That error would suggest that GetElementsByClass isnt a valid function for that object (again, I was going off the top of my head).

Comment: Turns out it is `GetElementsByClassName` and the correct object type is `HTMLDocument`.

Comment: @BrandonBarney changed the `promos` type from `IHTMLElementCollection` to `HTMLDocument` and change to `getElementsByClassName` but unfortunately it throws the exact same object error... am I missing something? (a lot I think)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150998/discussion-between-brandon-barney-and-dick-plixen).